# Web content that cannot be found in Google's index is considered unique content?

Tags: seo, google, google-search

What is the criteria for determining what unique content is? Is it content that cannot be found in Google's index? Or is there more to it?

Answer (score 1):

Unique content:

- Is not copied from elsewhere (exact copy)
- Is not a shorter summary of other content (i.e. some content is removed but the other content remains unmodified)

Quality content that won't be affected by the Panda Algorithm:

- Is written by an author who is knowledgeable about the subject
- Offers new and unique insight into the topic
- Cites sources for its information